# Making a 1000lb draw longbow

Tags: weapons, medieval

Let's say a character is nine feet tall (proportioned like a normal very fit human) with ten times the strength of a fairly strong man.  How could a bow be created with medieval technology to handle that force (draw length, material, and other details appreciated)?

P.S. This does obviously take place in a fantasy setting so any other ideas you have that use magic I would be glad to hear but is not required in answer.

Comment: Check this link: http://thearbalistguild.forumotion.com/t489-15th-century-military-crossbow-draw-weight

Comment: This question shows a lack of basic research. Medieval 1000-pound bows (crossbows and siege crossbows) existed and that would have been discovered with a single Google.

Comment: Yes obviously those siege crossbows existed and i knew of them, but as i stated i wanted a *bow* not a *cross*bow. However i do see where the misunderstanding, i should have clarified.

Comment: So use the same material as the bow part, is that not obvious?

Comment: Well their would be a lot of variables, for example the arms of the crossbow are much to short to be used, the draw length would be much different, and the acceleration of the arrow would vary greatly because of this.

Comment: "ideas you have that use magic I would be glad to hear" - if you're allowing magic, you don't need to ask, anything is possible! All you have to do is say, "Let there be a bow with a 1000lb draw"

Comment: Yes obviously, but the point of the question was to find a practical solution and if that wasn't possible *then* i would be willing to use magic as an excuse.

Comment: Also one thing to consider: 'draw weight' as a charateristic is like 'fuel consumption'. It doesn't represent wholey the power of the weapon. A 80lb composite recurve bow launches an arrow at 190 feet per second, while a 128lb longbow launches the same arrow at 170fps. What matters the most is projectile velocity and the momentum it brings to the target.

Comment: If you would be willing to provide resources on the effects of draw length i would gladly have a look at them unless you wish to clarify personally in the answers. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relatively easily!

Even during the western medieval period ✳here✳, steel crossbows were made that drew at about 1000 pounds. Just give your nine-footer one of those, sans stock, and show him where to shoot! I'm guessing you could make it longer --- obviously, a longer bow can shoot a longer arrow.

This is a totally realistic scenario not requiring any magic or anything other than well known military technology.

The record for a human is a 200 pound draw at full length. I daresay your very strong giant might be able to pull more than 1000 pounds, but that's neither here nor there. In a fantasy setting, I guess you could equip him with a small to mid-sized siege crossbow and let him shoot that!

Comment: Re "I guess you could equip him with a small to mid-sized siege crossbow...": Already been done. Detritus the troll, in various Discworld books.

Comment: I have thought about the cross bow before, but after some consideration i decided on making a longbow style weapon instead, so could one be made of steel and operated?

Comment: @ChristopherVoid The idea of a crossbow is to make drawing (and aiming) the bow easier. There is nothing special about the bow itself that I know of. But there is one issue you probably should think about : How much pull can the fingers of your giant handle? I'd recommend using a simple crossbow with some sort of a simple (and fast) lever based drawing aid. It would still be slower than a long bow but ease of aiming and convenience should make it worthwhile.

Comment: You make a good point and i should have been more clear that he could withstand any forces of the bow (fingers included) I simply wanted a bow from a stylistic standpoint and for, based on what i have heard, a faster rate of fire.

Comment: @ChristopherVoid A repeating crossbow might be an option. It uses the extra strength to operate the mechanism so its performance would be pretty close to what you want I think. Of course it looks nothing like you want. I think there were gloves and rings and such designed to protect fingers from bow strings, so it probably is not a big problem if you just remember about it.

Comment: @jamesqf: my point exactly! Although I daresay the OP's character would be unable to draw Detritus's 2000 pound piece of machinery!

Comment: @ChristopherVoid: sure, if your character is strong enough to cock a steel crossbow without assistance from the mechanism he won't need the wooden stock the piece of metal rests in. He can just draw the bow itself! And yeah, with just the bow, he'll naturally have a faster rate of fire: take a look at Lars Andersen's archery techniques on the Youtubes. I would nòt want to face your nine foot tall warrior dashing about with a 1000 pound bow whizzing arrows this way and that the way Larsen does!

Comment: That was the image i thought about as well! Thankyou for the input, i also thought the bow would be better for mounted shooting than the crossbow although im not sure about that. And ill check out the videos, thanks again!

Comment: @ChristopherVoid: yeah, I would not opt for your character to wield a crossbow. That's wasted potential. From what I understand, even though a crossbow might rate 1000 pounds, it's not fully drawn the way a longbow is. And that's where the power comes from! A 1000 pound crossbow sans stock and mechanism drawn by a nine foot tall giant will be quite the formidable weapon. If he's part of a crack squad of Larsenesque shooters, then woe be the enemy that faces them! They'll soil their hauberks before the big archers ever get in range!

Comment: Should the italicized word "here" be a link?

Comment: ill have to do some digging on both ideas, although my giant has a bit of a thing for crafting weapons so why not both for different situations i guess!

Comment: @JBH: no, sorry about that! I always forget that stars cause italicisation here at Stack Exchange. It is now a very old worldbuilding convention to differentiate objects, actions and things of ✳here✳ in the primary world or ✳there✳ in the other world by use of these orthogonally deictic pronouns. For a more detailed description, see: http://www.frathwiki.com/Conlang_terminology#Deictic_Terms

Comment: @ChristopherVoid: sure, why not two! Though I do think that if he's quick enough, he'll come to appreciate the ordinary bow over the more fiddly crossbow. But I guess we'll have to wait until you describe him further and tell his story more completely!

Comment: @ChristopherVoid Don't forget to consider ammunition while thinking about that, you'll probably want the ammunition to be heavier and sturdier. (Forces applied to arrow on release are proportional to length and acceleration, acceleration is inversely proportional to mass.) Which probably forces a crossbow solution at some force level.

Comment: Ive been looking for a site with a more discussion based format for brainstorming and discussing characters more , unfortunately ive yet to find one, and i do agree on the bow, however the crossbow will be his "Heavy Hitter" that will have a weight that even he will need a windlass for!

Comment: @Ville Niemi yeah i would imagine the forces would shatter a arrow before leaving the bow, do you have any recommendations for material or other changes on the arrows specifically?

Comment: @ChristopherVoid Not really, but realistically you'd want to keep the arrow speed, length, and mass distribution the same so I think using the same materials but scaling the weight linearly with the force and putting the extra mass on heavier point and thicker shaft would be close enough for fiction.

Comment: @ChristopherVoid Oops, you talked about the bow being longer. That would scale the draw length which would scale the shaft length.

Comment: No problem, i have to go and figure out what materials and measurements would keep the arrow from shattering lol

Comment: BTW, If you're looking for a site that has a discussion based format and encourages brainstorming/discussion of characters, you're in the wrong place. @ChristopherVoid

Comment: I realize i said i was *Looking* for one.

Comment: @ChristopherVoid: there are many places designed for discussion. Aify is right: this is a Q&A forum. If you are looking for general discussion on worldbuilding, I'd recommend CBB (http://aveneca.com/cbb/) as they have a strong and active community there. I could be wrong, but it looks like you might be a writer in search for a community. In that case, I think Mythic Scribes might be up your alley! (https://mythicscribes.com) They, too, are fantasy oriented and I think might be of benefit to you as most everyone there is either writing or is working on the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reccomendations the sound like something i would like to use for general discussion unlike this which i try to use for specific (mostly science and physics oriented) questions

Comment: @ChristopherVoid: Well, I hope to see you in one, the other or both!